# how to load .hbm files while deploying the project

Tags: hibernate

I am developing a web application using JSF2.1 with Hibernate3.5. As i observed that, after i gave the first request only all the .hbm files are loading but i want to load all .hbm files at the time of deploying the project.
How can i achieve this, i mean what configuration i need to add, so that it will load while deploying?
Here is my .cfg file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
     <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory name="factory">
            <property name="connection.datasource">java:/PAEDIATRICS</property>
        </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

---

```
    public class HibernateUtil {
        private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        static {
            try {
                // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 

                Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
                configuration.configure("hibernate/entitymapping/general/hibernate.cfg.xml");
                System.out.println("Hibernate Configuration loaded");

                sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                // Log the exception. 
                System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
                ex.printStackTrace();
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
            }
        }

        public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            return sessionFactory;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where you configure the `SessionFactory`?

Comment: @v.ladynev i configured the datasource at server side. And i am calling it by property 'connection.datasource'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SessionFactory` is created only when you do `HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()` in the first time, because of `static` initialization.

The simplest way to do a configuration on the server startup is use `ServletContextListener`.

```
public class ApplicationInitializer implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    }

}
```

You need to add `ApplicationInitializer` to the `web.xml`.